# How to decrease text entry display length in Xamarin form?

Tags: xamarin

my text display is very long, I want to decrease the text display, can anyone help me please. Thank you

```
<Entry x:Name="Email" Placeholder="Email\Login ID" Keyboard="Email" PlaceholderColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="Black"/>
```

[text entry display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F3vJ.png)

Comment: HorizontalOptions="Start" or/and set WidthRequest

Comment: @Cfun thank you so much ! Need to set HorizontalOptions = "Start" and WidthRequest together. Gratitude !

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
<Entry x:Name="Email" Placeholder="Email\Login ID" Keyboard="Email" PlaceholderColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="Start" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Start" WidthRequest="220"/>
```